# Could not resolve com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-messages:3.9.1

Tags: javascript, java, android, reactjs, react-native

I am developing react native video Chang app using quickblox.
But I install quickblox module and run the project, the error occurs like the following.
How can I fix this error?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add below code to your project's **`build.gradle`** file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk-releases/raw/master/"

        }
    }
}
```